# How Do I Create a Multidimensional Array in Python Via Multiplication in a Loop?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

I am trying to multiply individual elements in an array with a dataframe of 5 columns to get a multidimensional array of ndim(5, 5, 2),
however, the code I am using gives me `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,2) (5,5)`.

Below is the data I am using

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#the array
v = np.array([6.51481987, 2.13390696])

#the df
X = {'icept': 0    1
 1    1
 2    1
 3    1
 4    1
 Name: icept, dtype: int32,
 'pvl': 0    2.533680
 1    4.255814
 2    2.269452
 3    2.930867
 4    3.555830
 Name: pvl, dtype: float64,
 'ed': 0    4.869460
 1    6.401434
 2    7.907954
 3    3.510557
 4    6.225850
 Name: ed, dtype: float64,
 'fins': 0    0.744995
 1    1.746176
 2    0.866215
 3    0.820449
 4    0.973149
 Name: fins, dtype: float64,
 'hp': 0    4.586429
 1    3.873337
 2    4.362893
 3    4.133550
 4    5.576006
 Name: hp, dtype: float64}
```

And here is the code I am using to create what I want to do, which gives me the error.

```
v2 = [[[0 for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(2)]
for i in enumerate(v):
    v2[:, :, i] = [i] * np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of terms of R scripts and how they worked when I posted the question, but have figured it out by using a dictionary approach.

The code that worked for me is below:

```
v2 = {}
for i in v:
    v2[i] = [i] * np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X)
```

It created a multidimensional array in a dictionary that I can work with.